# MySQL SubQuery WHERE IN, but also get additional column from IN subquery

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This is slipping my mind at the moment, so let's say I have this code:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
    WHERE (FoundCity, FoundState) IN
    ( SELECT city, state, distance
      FROM Table2
    ) ;
```

How do I also get it to pull the distance column above into the 'main' query?

Comment: look in to [subqueries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/from-clause-subqueries.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the subquery to a join. You can then select any of the columns from either table.

```
SELECT *,  t2.distance
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2
ON t1.FoundCity = t2.city AND t1.FoundState = t2.state
```

**Edit**

If you want to keep the Tuple join syntax, you can also do:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.distance
    FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2
    ON (t1.FoundCity, t1.FoundState) = (t2.city, t2.state);
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fe644/3)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 as T1
LEFT JOIN Table2 as T2 on T1.FoundCity = T2.FoundCity AND T1.FoundState = T2.FoundState
```

Better idea would be to use Left join. And in * you can include column names you desire using T1 as prefix for columns from table 1 and T2 for table 2. (ex: T2.state)